# Terminal Software for ROS/Ubuntu?

Tags: serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently used http://realterm.sourceforge.net/ in Windows-7. Is there any such Terminal Software suitable for ROS or may be specific to Ubuntu ? It is a great help since it scans for open ports in my computer, and once connected, can send commands and receive data from device/robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45857/terminal-software-for-ros/ubuntu-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For serial comms I use `gtkterm`. There is also `minicom`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2012-10-16**:
Good to know!  Answers my question on how to access comm port with terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`cutecom` is also a good solution

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-02**:
@WilliamWoodall Lovely interface, but could not get the roomba to work via it '! :-(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On behalf of the greybeards out there, I'll mention `kermit`, available in Ubuntu as `ckermit`.  I used to prefer it to minicom, although it's been years since I've used either.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2